# "No providerId parameter given in Shibboleth SSO authentication request" from TestShib with ruby-saml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth, saml

I am trying to implement OmniAuth SSO-only authentication in a Rails 5 app with Devise. I am trying to use TestShib to test before using our organisations in-house IdP.

This is my current configuration in `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
idp_meta_parser = OneLogin::RubySaml::IdpMetadataParser.new
idp_meta = idp_meta_parser.parse_remote_to_hash('https://idp.testshib.org/idp/shibboleth')
config.omniauth :saml,
    issuer: 'https://localhost:3000/shibboleth',
    **idp_meta
```

When navigating to the auth URL (`/users/auth/saml`) I'm redirected to an error page on TestShib, and the log says this:

```
10:01:19.187 - DEBUG [edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.idp.profile.IdPProfileHandlerManager:86] - shibboleth.HandlerManager: Looking up profile handler for request path: /Shibboleth/SSO
10:01:19.188 - DEBUG [edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.idp.profile.IdPProfileHandlerManager:97] - shibboleth.HandlerManager: Located profile handler of the following type for the request path: edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.idp.profile.saml1.ShibbolethSSOProfileHandler
10:01:19.188 - DEBUG [edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.idp.util.HttpServletHelper:339] - LoginContext key cookie was not present in request
10:01:19.188 - DEBUG [edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.idp.profile.saml1.ShibbolethSSOProfileHandler:152] - Incoming request does not contain a login context, processing as first leg of request
10:01:19.188 - DEBUG [edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.idp.profile.saml1.ShibbolethSSOProfileHandler:218] - Decoding message with decoder binding urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0:profiles:AuthnRequest
10:01:19.188 - WARN [edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.idp.profile.saml1.ShibbolethSSODecoder:72] - No providerId parameter given in Shibboleth SSO authentication request.
10:01:19.188 - WARN [edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.idp.profile.saml1.ShibbolethSSOProfileHandler:247] - Error decoding Shibboleth SSO request
org.opensaml.ws.message.decoder.MessageDecodingException: No providerId parameter given in Shibboleth SSO authentication request.
    at edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.idp.profile.saml1.ShibbolethSSODecoder.doDecode(ShibbolethSSODecoder.java:73) ~[shibboleth-identityprovider-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.opensaml.ws.message.decoder.BaseMessageDecoder.decode(BaseMessageDecoder.java:79) ~[openws-1.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.opensaml.saml1.binding.decoding.BaseSAML1MessageDecoder.decode(BaseSAML1MessageDecoder.java:109) ~[opensaml-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.idp.profile.saml1.ShibbolethSSOProfileHandler.decodeRequest(ShibbolethSSOProfileHandler.java:240) [shibboleth-identityprovider-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.idp.profile.saml1.ShibbolethSSOProfileHandler.performAuthentication(ShibbolethSSOProfileHandler.java:174) [shibboleth-identityprovider-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.idp.profile.saml1.ShibbolethSSOProfileHandler.processRequest(ShibbolethSSOProfileHandler.java:153) [shibboleth-identityprovider-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.idp.profile.saml1.ShibbolethSSOProfileHandler.processRequest(ShibbolethSSOProfileHandler.java:70) [shibboleth-identityprovider-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.common.profile.ProfileRequestDispatcherServlet.service(ProfileRequestDispatcherServlet.java:83) [shibboleth-common-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) [catalina.jar:6.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.36]
    at edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.idp.util.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:50) [shibboleth-identityprovider-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.36]
    at edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.idp.session.IdPSessionFilter.doFilter(IdPSessionFilter.java:87) [shibboleth-identityprovider-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.36]
    at edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.common.log.SLF4JMDCCleanupFilter.doFilter(SLF4JMDCCleanupFilter.java:52) [shibboleth-common-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:6.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [catalina.jar:6.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470) [catalina.jar:6.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [catalina.jar:6.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:6.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [catalina.jar:6.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293) [catalina.jar:6.0.36]
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.36]
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:311) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.36]
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.36]
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.36]
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.36]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_55]
```

I have found nothing really relevant online, and the only documentation I can find that mentions providerId is [this on the Shibboleth Wiki](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdPUnsolicitedSSO).

What exactly is the `providerId` and how can I specify it with OmniAuth and RubySaml?

Answer (score 1):

So this took forever to figure out. Essentially I tracked down all the docs (https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/IDP30/UnsolicitedSSOConfiguration) and looked on a few email list. What you are missing is part of the redirect query. It usually looks something like this:

```
https://idp.testshib.org/idp/profile/Shibboleth/SSO?SAMLRequest=rVbZjqraFv0Vk3rwoWLRSGt2VbJoRFAoEGn05YZmgSh9I8rXX7T2rlTt3HPOPslNgLDmms1Ycwxm%2BNF4WVouQNce8y2sOti0E9A0sG6TIueLvOkyWJuwviQBtLab1%2BmxbcsFgtAsOidRwnvJ47o4vyQF4o0pYN4mgdcWNXJP2yARDsN5RPkzCoXUjAiZYOZBhp6xDO7hlBdQvg8RL2imE2EsnOTevepHjWYskoTlSztuNMfEfynq%2BG5AyrqIkhQi5mj0ixS2R8Q036cTWXid%2FgfHGRYPCXZGs%2BxYEGXImc8Q1AwlUHKOURTlz4PRtWk6KOdN6%2BXt6xRHMWaGzsdrhzELnFwQ2GE6sWHdPMDgL%2Bh0cs3SvFncD%2FU67ep8UXhN0ixyL4PNog0WJlA3i9Fx4f1q3deQ8u9jxgO1RVCk07cfd%2B%2FFA1399v9vdAZbL%2FRa7wfytc6PsFmYSTz2vqvhT9Rh80l03%2Fcv%2FfzRfRxFUQRlkdEnbJL4afoZC0M5j4rHkvfyIh%2BxpcnwYFMdCSrCCUjjok7aY%2FYXiTEEQ%2B%2BJZ%2FAazAKMyJ%2BmyHdof5wIJX4hnGVFDZ%2Fqxps1Rw8nqZ8ptzCCNcwDOLG28uv06c9U8wjd1V7eREWdNd%2BX%2FwjrW%2BNgfoFpUcJw1vw63U9of57wfzTs7QcMFnIepF2TXKB2F1rpBbCZ6DWMkusmaUa1P4Uw8rq0nTyU%2BXhOwmZyvV%2FJJAt%2FCRcG%2F4op5Cv435YfvRKSePyU%2FyWLI0tP37j7yGJ7aQfffN5ruVMeZwxtiih%2BHALOu5FzYEUEurvN5VgPhk0Vn4ud%2BPpA9DX4YfhUwsfyNyl%2FSu8jwpL2MUkjc9fM3RKLKHGX09aOZXmS3wXVcy2bO9pAXS6Iap2rDrVZHjz5ue1xpmSYTDEdWVxqYd4RxlElt32L6VTGz0%2BRTtC2uVkbMdyfcQQO%2FiWudzxOgURyFBe7WcQh0s6I05nVHCN1YdDcYmV6HWosuQGcIj%2F18VpQZNYzLvPoGFMAXXXbqvZrN0LtQD7vQmoXr1iJVZYKonr6VTzIbteZZMdG7np9q8qodXcWajIxq6YuchouzwGWEx2tVHvdw5PkiCEszdnDDkOWfCojzloMD41mn4kW4gi%2BJYtVD07qXMHI1aHsd%2F5%2BYDeRRq1v6ZZ%2FllHc1CkqEchMwp8pfcA02UD3eByoTsi8frb%2BS6%2Fv7V%2FD2ycVLomywji6Phf8fcxG9xkI31RZFsyB58FpHYNe5kA83gLQuPhcHc%2BJxPYoBwx0OdoQ1Wh63tgLtmFIYq9gwSBuVHCWAGaJPBi3UPEqDPdYzeZAoXJn7Oi52sU%2FiabKgYcf6HvFd5ZlgLPdJksvKke4wk4kVEHt1ZM8aMK%2B19LibiN%2Fs%2FX6l3rcUeVDV73yA1A%2B6sXjlsapBtMLHxjXAjhoeycdfJy4iidgfPipKu%2F8xJWQpX8%2Fu6neY5R1cZCPl0ADhshxBhDiWByf477R8OM7DzYyOSA3rYJ%2BSmLdymPnLiJl8RVsZTkA66Y6bJF3t77qKH0SyVtsLW03mp8LpY%2FE3L8dFO66YtPKMvd4KIVicHWuWvS%2BucVcxG5ORYqY3ZXul5mmHND1yS1BrUBCj3NOqsvj4Ah0xaxXQxQkz0tSKqB%2Bs6juQjmSldjpRlAPwU1IV%2FZ%2BGXT8jQA8ZSFHWwfMBvDPfWYIZr8MzrfW57j1LuHXbVMMkdG6zC12SoVhpRAXElNmjvFpX5E%2Bm5wk%2BG7N4d5sWYplx3NG7fWm1gpN6VrV505o8RGjV1bA4umNLuGAGVSxZ89W5514iyYNszTryr2RiGOpV9X31EOJvFOxLYEz0HZgxdz06xz1R%2Bo4AKSTJXDvKofe%2BQ2F2HA4bqustrpTYZDD825F2yh9QCU54dPjZQDRnc%2BVqYqSAJz4733Vh%2B9WFbndqGRjhagAlXizkkzZnwsj34JhAUDc9Q%2FsxCW4XIRYwbXOgAeBJMAz7W9VlaaqWAijYNtzYTRnrBjNZNNymF0dO4aj7wgG898vVSR1V%2Ffc0s%2Fp%2B8Zfque9uxGP%2BEqPOgV6g8hvrJV7SVvIHHzcDxo4pouu20E6HBMpjny0EFaHpjtBcXtaLyXHrJGMcZYktBpaRjohEE7hka6y8rk%2FJYrKYmJWqBuFLDcVla4pXtHzuGyIrK7qK2Zbz1pCWUJMWHRN81q5MRr5lriHXhMVWpN71E82zfwmtKTeZ1Z3tXd2viF0y1kvyz1txrZgryFydMeGBZIUD%2FoKQMOihEaUIqBuSTjKRzS9wi7ld687WDaTL7UUnqhbtPbOMhKlvcUQGGW8fgyr3wfQp%2FFjRCFfh9e34fb28ev1%2FX%2F77b8%3D
```

What is missing is part of the query string in the params. The method you are using is SAML 1.x. Simple include your providerId, shire, and target as part of the redirect URL. The result should look something like this:

https://idp.testshib.org/idp/profile/Shibboleth/SSO?SAMLRequest=xxx&providerId=xxx&shire=xxx&target=xxx

Alternately you could use the SAML 2 endpoint `https://idp.testshib.org/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO` which requires less of these parameters.